# How to making loop to determine which variable will be picked up on JS

Tags: javascript, function

I create several arrays and each array are different from each other. I want to take a number of user and according to that number the function should pick correct array, but I declare the names of arrays according to possible user input. Like there is RPS1 and RPS2 these are two different arrays and if the user enter 1 the function should return RPS1. I already made it with if else stuff, but is there any shortcut to do this because I will add much more arrays. (Sorry for bad explanation this is my first time in this community)

```
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var RPS0 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    var RPS1 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard'];
    var RPS2 = ['just', 'over', 'crowd'];
    var RPSi;

    if( i == 0 ) {
        RPSi = RPS0;
    } else if(i==1){
        RPSi = RPS1;
    } else {
        RPSi = RPS2;
    }
    return(RPSi);
}
```

Comment: _"but is there any shortcut to do this"_ - Yes, an array.  `[ ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'], ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'], ... ]`

Comment: Yeah it is a way but i want to declare RPS1 RPS2 ... with in a loop or something like that or am i wrong at some point (in logical way)?

Answer (score 1):

just make an array of arrays then you will get required array by index

```
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var RPSs = [
        ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
        ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard']
    ]

    return RPSs[i]
}
```

Comment: You're missing the "default" branch.

Comment: @Andreas, could you explain what does it mean?

Comment: `RPS2` will be returned when `i` is not zero or one. I'm not sure why OP wants the "last" option in any cases other than `i == 0` or `i == 1`, but the "working" code does exactly this.

Comment: @Andreas, no, it is not default it is just meaningless in if else construction write the last condition

Comment: _"meaningless"_ or not, it's in the working code of OP. `DecisionArray(234)` returns `RPS2` with OPs code, but `undefined` with your code.

Comment: So my code is working more correctly than OP code, obviously DecisionArray(234) should return undefind, not last item

Comment: _"So my code is working more correctly"_ - This might be the case, or this statement might just be cocky. OPs code has a default value (which btw. is absolutely a legitimate use case, so why do you think _"obviously DecisionArray(234) should return undefind"_), yours has not. That's all I've said.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var RPS0 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    var RPS1 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard'];
    var RPS2 = ['just', 'over', 'crowd'];
    var all = { RPS0, RPS1, RPS2 };
    return all[`RPS${i}`]
}

console.log(DecisionArrays(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var RPS = [];
    RPS.push(['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']);
    RPS.push(['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard']);
    RPS.push(['just', 'over', 'crowd']);
    return RPS[i]
}
```

EDIT:
the function that you wrote will always return the last option as the default, whenever `i` is not matched to one of the valid options. This is probably not wha you want. By using my proposed solution you will get the value `undefined` for any invalid value of `i`

Comment: You're missing the "default" branch.

Comment: I disagree, in the question there was no request for a default answer. In this case, any index out of the defined array will return undefined, which is a much more meaningful result IMHO for a case like this

Comment: If it is _"more meaningful"_ or not is a decision that OP has to make. But OPs code clearly returns `RPS2` when `i` is not zero or one, hence when you call `DecisionArrays` with `324` it will also return `RPS2`

Comment: the OP is clearly a beginner that probably didn't even think about that case. I will edit my answer to make him realise what I think is a misjudgement mistake

Answer (score 0):

As @Andreas suggested, you can use `array of arrays`:

```
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var rps = [
        ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
        ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard'],
        ['just', 'over', 'crowd']
    ];

    return rps[i];
}
```

or if you need little bit more control on `i` tat comes from user, use `object`:

```
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var rps = {
        11: ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
        12: ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard'],
        13: ['just', 'over', 'crowd']
    };

    return rps[i];
}
```

Comment: I can't understand the 11 12 13 numbers existence. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: it's just an example, let's say you have, for some reason, answer from your users not sequential numbers, but some specific, like 11, 12, 13. Then, if you will create array and insert at index 11 an item, then you'll get 10 empty (undefined) values before it (index 0-10), and this can lead to unexpected results.

Comment: I don't know specifics of your app, but it's common practice to use tens or even hundreds when you count something, to have enough space to play if you have to add new option. As an example: if you make some kind of ticketing system, and wanna let user pick from some list of common problems, you'd probably like to use for all account issues 100+id of problem, then for billing, 200+id, and so on, and then, even if you have only 3 items for first hundreds slice (101, 102, 103) you'll have 96 "slots" to add another problems to that list in the future.

Comment: Project that to previous comment and you'll see what benefits can "object" usage give to you.

Answer (score 0):

There are more efficient ways of doing this, but i wouldn't call it a shortcut as per say. the beauty of javascript is that there are many ways of doing the same thing.

How i would have done it is:

```
function decisionArrays (i) {
    var arrays = [
        ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'],
        ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard'],
        ['just', 'over', 'crowd']
    ];
    return arrays[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `switch` statement could also be an option:

```
function DecisionArrays(i) {
    var RPS0 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
    var RPS1 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors', 'Lizzard'];
    var RPS2 = ['just', 'over', 'crowd'];

    switch(i){
      case 0:  return RPS0;
      case 1:  return RPS1;
      default: return RPS2;
    }
}
```